# Hilbert functions of polynomial growth

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R=k[x_1, \dots , x_n]$. Let $M$ be a graded $R$-module whose hilbert function $h(i):=\text{dim}_kM_i$ is well-defined and grows like a polynomial. Is $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module?

Comment: Take $M = R$ with trivial $R$ action.